# execv() quirks concerning arguments

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to output the results of 'ps' for an assignment, but I've ran into some slight quirks that I'd like to figure out.

This works correctly, and displays ps's output in the shell:

```
//Create "ps -u laser"
int pid_ps = fork();
char *argv[1] = {"-u laser"};
if (pid_ps == 0) {
   execv("/bin/ps", argv);
}
```

Now, this is the format that was given in my slides, but just gives the "usage:" and "format is one or more of:" notifications for ps when it's run:

```
//Create "ps -u laser"
int pid_ps = fork();
char *argv[2] = {"-u", "laser"};
if (pid_ps == 0) {
   execv("/bin/ps", argv);
}
```

I also tried putting 0 and NULL on the end of the array, which was suggested in other answers, but no luck.

I'm probably overlooking something minor, but I'm not too familiar with c. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure either of these are correct.  Are you sure that `char *argv[] = {"-u", "laser", NULL};` doesn't work?

Comment: Just doubled checked, still gives the "format" and "usage" messages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `char *argv[] = {"/bin/ps", "-u", "laser", 0};` - the first argument is the executable name.

EDIT: Sample.

```
int pid_ps = fork();
if (pid_ps == 0) {
  char *argv[] = {"/bin/ps", "-u", "laser", 0};
  execv("/bin/ps", argv);
}
```

The above snippet is tested and working.

Comment: Or you could just pass `"ps"` as `argv[0]`; there's really no need for the full pathname there.

Comment: For some reason I was getting errors without the full pathname. Also the execv fails when placing both the program name and arguments in the same array.

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting. Never would have thought to have the ps argument twice. Works, like you said, and cleaner than my original method. Thanks Erik.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Library Functions Manual for exec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) (emphasis mine):

> The `char *const argv[]` argument is an array of pointers to null-
> terminated strings that represent the argument list available to
> the new program. **The first argument, by convention, should point
> to the filename associated with the file being executed.**  The
> array of pointers must be terminated by a null pointer.

Thus if you want to run `ps -u laser` using `execv`, `argv` could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        char *const argv[] = {
            "ps",         // executable's filename
            "-u",         // flag
            "laser",      // argument
            (char *) NULL // mark the end
        };

        execv(
            "/bin/ps", // executable
            argv
        );
    }
    
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Now, if you don't care about `argv`'s first argument being the executable's path, you can do the following instead, as [Erik has done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687939/10824322):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        char *const argv[] = {
            "/bin/ps",    // executable/filename
            "-u",         // flag
            "laser",      // argument
            (char *) NULL // mark the end
        };

        execv(argv[0], argv);
    }

    wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: I asked this question 10+ years ago for my operating systems class, and am still learning new things - the manual entry is quite helpful. Cheers @uzluisf